# Block elements inside a product list

Tags: html, css

I have a page which contains a products' list.

I decided to use an unordered list instead of divs to display the products but there is a  problem with that, since I can't insert other block level elements in the `<li>` to achieve some specific design I want (an image with some background, bordered descriptions, floated links etc etc....).

My questions are:

1. Is it possible and semantically correct to use inline elements in the `<li>` (such as `<span>`) to achieve such visualisations?
2. Is it semantically correct to use a div instead (and H2, P tags in it)?
3. Generaly, how would you markup a product list in which every product contains:

   1. an image;
   2. the product's name; and
   3. a link "more".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A supremely semantic way would be a model used on dukevideo.com.

```
<ol>
   <li>
      <span id="lia">
         <span class="productImage">
            <a href="/Bikes/DVD/American-Chopper/American-Chopper-Series-1.aspx" title="American Chopper Complete Series 1">
               <img src="/images/imageCache/bddc1cee608a8fb5927d6521ff1f0eb0.jpg" alt="American Chopper Complete Series 1" />
            </a>
          </span>
          <span class="price">
          <dl class="prices">
            <dt class="hidden strikethru">Price:</dt>
            <dd class="price red">£29.36</dd>
            <dt class="hidden">Our Price:</dt>
            <dd class="price">£25.36</dd>
          </dl>
       </span>
       <span class="title">
          <a href="/Bikes/DVD/American-Chopper/American-Chopper-Series-1.aspx" title="American Chopper Complete Series 1">American Chopper Complete Series 1
          </a>
       </span>
     </span>
     <span id="lib">
       <input type="image" class="buyLink" src="/images/buy.png" alt="Add to Basket" id="AC1" name="buyProduct_AC1" value="buyProductAC1"  />
     </span>
  </li>
```

(On the real site the markup has been remade - and invalidated. My successor isu sing DIV inside LIs instead of SPANs)

This semantic markup is quite heavy, but is super semantic. A search engine or screen reader would work well on it. It allowed us to differentiate parts of the product spec in a list form.

Hopefully the classes give an indication what the CSS is doing. eg.:
*.hidden - hides content from screen but not from screen readers, search engines
*.red - makes text red
*.strikethru - strikes-thru text, to give an illustration of slashed pricing
*.title - bolder face

Comment: I disagree with using "red", "hidden", and "strikethru" as classnames.  Not semantic at all (even if it's for humans).  What if you decide to change the red price text to a dim colour globally?

Comment: Hello Program.X and thanks for your help.
I have one question on this code:
Is it correct to put a block-level element (< dl >) in an inline element ( < span > )?

Comment: @spyros, I'm not sure that /is/ legal.  I think divs will be more appropriate here in place of the spans.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't we then spoil the hierarchy of the block-level elements by putting a div inside a li?

Comment: @spyros, Not sure what you mean by that.  "hierarchy of block-level elements" ?

Comment: A DIV is implicitly a block, so should not be within an LI. AFAIK. Take your point about "red", etc. (I mean, what if red is redefined? ;) ). Maybe "reduced" or "seo" would be better options.

Comment: @strager, I'm sorry. Here's a link:http://www.ahuka.com/htmllevel1/blocklevel.html (read the last paragraph "The Hierarchy").
What it says in general terms is that we can't put div inside any other block-level element.

Comment: @spyros, That's incorrect.  You can put block-level elements in other block-level elements.

Comment: You can do it for sure, but is it valid?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3
Check this link for example, where it says "Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline elements" thus no block elements.

(correct me if I'm wrong of course, I'm still learning :) )

Comment: @spyros and @Program.X, <li>s are block level elements and can contain other block level elements. <span>s are inline level and cannot contain block level elements. Just checked with the XHTML DTD.

Comment: @baxter, you are absolutely right. The page (with a div inside a li) passed the validation test.

Answer (score 1):

1. The most important part of your HTML is that it makes semantic sense. If you want to display an inline element as a block level element that's perfectly acceptable, provided the HTML behind it makes sense. This is an important part of being able to separate content from presentation.
2. Generally, if you can describe something as a list then it *should* be an HTML list, either a `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<dl>`. It's not a strict rule, but a good guideline. If you don't want to follow that guideline then it's ok to use `<div>`s, as long as you don't put block level elements inside inline elements.
3. Keeping the markup as simple as possible I would say it should look as follows:

   ```
   <dl>
     <dt>Product name</dt>
     <dd>
       <img src="product.jpg" alt="Product name" />
       Description.
       <a class="read-more" href="#">Read more about Product name</a>
     </dd>
   </dl>
   ```

For some additional information on styling `<dl>`s [Max Design's "Definition lists - misused or misunderstood?"](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/definition/) has a list of different styles that might be useful.

Comment: Hello baxter, I came up with something like this a minute ago, but I faced the problem of grouping the elements (dt + dd) of each product.
I have to put the products side by side and to achieve this I would have to include them in a floated left container.
How can I do that with dt+dd?

Thanks again

Comment: @spyros, Apply float: left; to the dt.  Use selectors, not inline styles, for this.

Comment: @spyros, without knowing what you want it's hard to make any suggestions, although strager's is a good place to start.

I've updated the answer with some links to resources for styling `<dl>`s, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers (@baxter, I googled and found the same link - it's very nice).

What I'm  trying to do specifically is to show 2 products/row.
Each product will have an image on the left and on its right the product's name and underneath it a link "more".

Answer (score 0):

1. `<span>` is the "tofu of HTML", just like `<div>`. It can usually be inserted anywhere, but if you wanna be sure, I would suggest your try it out and then have the HTML tested on [the W3C validation page](http://validator.w3.org/).

   Or better even, if you're using Firefox, use the [HTML Validator add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/249). I know it says Windows-only, but on their website, there are version for Linux and OS X aswell.
2. Yes.
3. I would use either an unordered list, like you are doing here, or a [Data List](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_dl.asp).